# Hibernate: updating associated objects

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables say parent and child.

**PARENT STRUCTURE**

ID  ||  NAME

primary key is ID

**CHILD STRUCTURE**

ID  ||  NAME  ||  PAREND_ID

primary key is ID

foreign key is PARENT_ID

**The parent class is as follows:**

```
class parent {
private String id;
private String name;
//getter and setter methods
}
```

**The child class is as follows**

```
class child {
private String id;
private String name;
private String parent_id;
//getter and setter methods
}
```

The hibernate mapping for parent is as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "parent" table="parent"></class>
<id.....>....<id>
<property name = "name" column = "NAME"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "child" table="child"></class>
<id.....>....<id>
<property name = "name" column = "NAME"/>
<property name = "parent_id" column = "PARENT_ID"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want that if I change the id of parent, the parent_id column in child table should also get updated with the new value. Also the association is unidirectional from parent to child and one parent can have many child.
Can you help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are not associated with each other. There is not much that you can do. Hibernate just does not know that they are related.
You need to introduce actual assiciations.

Also, changing primary key of the existing object does not sound as right design decision.

Comment: I want that if i change the id of parent, the parent_id in child table should get updated. I know my classed are not associated. What changes do i need to make. Thanks

Comment: sorry, my bad. I updated the answer. I really think you may want  to revisit your design. Or provide more context on what you are trying to achieve that you need to change object's primary key.

Comment: I want that if i change the id in parent table, the parent_id column in child table should get updated to new value. I want something like this:                                                            Parent p = (Parent)session.get(Parent.class, "1");        p.setId("2");                                                          Now as soon as i do this, all the parent id's in child table should get updated to new value(i.e. "2").                               Please tell me the changes i require. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The actual problem is as follows: i have a state and some districts in that state. I want to shift a few districts to a different state for which i will have the change the district code of districts i am shifting. Now my district code is already referenced in many tables. So i just want to update the district code in base table and the updated value should get reflected in the associated tables.

Comment: If you have foreign key constraint you may not be able to do it(dependong on specific database). Generally, primary key should not be changed. In any case, can you come up with a sql that would do what you want?

Comment: Ok, say that the district table has id as primary key and some other table say funds_received has foreign key reference with district table. Now if i update district and set district_code = '2' it will automatically update the funds_received table and replace the existing district_code with '2' because of foreign key reference.

Comment: I was asking about sql to update the whole thing. In general, Hibernate does not like unrelated objects and it may not be possible to do such thing in one shot. If there is no foreign key constraint between tables, you may be able issue two updates - first to update all children that refer to old parent id and then update parent. But if you are designing the schema you should not use for key something that can be changed so easily. Just introduce synthetic key and district id as separate column. Children then will refer to this key and don't have to change.